# JAX VMAP Parallelization Details

Tags: python, vectorization, jax

I was wondering how vmap's internals work.
When I vectorize code using jax.lax.map, I know that each element is executed consecutively. However when I use vmap I execute the vectorized operation apparently in parallel. Can someone provide me with a more detailed explanation of how the parallelization works? How does Jax determine the number of parallel processes, and can this behaviour be influenced by the user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jax.vmap` is a vectorizing/batching transform, not a parallelizing transform. Internally, it converts an unbatched function to a batched function, lowering to efficient primitive calls rather than an explicit map or loop.

For example, here is a simple function, where we create both a manually-looped and an automatically vectorized batched version:

```py
import jax
import numpy as np
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(x, y):
  return x @ y

num_batches = 3
num_entries = 5

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.rand(num_batches, num_entries)
y = np.random.rand(num_batches, num_entries)


f_loop = lambda x, y: jnp.stack([f(xi, yi) for xi, yi in zip(x, y)])
f_vmap = jax.vmap(f)

print(f_loop(x, y))
# [1.3567398 2.1908383 1.6315514]
print(f_vmap(x, y))
# [1.3567398 2.1908383 1.6315514]
```

These return the same results (by design), but they are quite different under the hood; by printing the [jaxpr](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jaxpr.html), we see that the loop version requires a long sequence of XLA calls:

```py
print(jax.make_jaxpr(f_loop)(x, y))
```

```
{ lambda ; a:f32[3,5] b:f32[3,5]. let
    c:f32[1,5] = slice[limit_indices=(1, 5) start_indices=(0, 0) strides=(1, 1)] a
    d:f32[5] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] c
    e:f32[1,5] = slice[limit_indices=(1, 5) start_indices=(0, 0) strides=(1, 1)] b
    f:f32[5] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] e
    g:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] d f
    h:f32[1,5] = slice[limit_indices=(2, 5) start_indices=(1, 0) strides=(1, 1)] a
    i:f32[5] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] h
    j:f32[1,5] = slice[limit_indices=(2, 5) start_indices=(1, 0) strides=(1, 1)] b
    k:f32[5] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] j
    l:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] i k
    m:f32[1,5] = slice[limit_indices=(3, 5) start_indices=(2, 0) strides=(1, 1)] a
    n:f32[5] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] m
    o:f32[1,5] = slice[limit_indices=(3, 5) start_indices=(2, 0) strides=(1, 1)] b
    p:f32[5] = squeeze[dimensions=(0,)] o
    q:f32[] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([0], [0]), ([], []))] n p
    r:f32[1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1,)] g
    s:f32[1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1,)] l
    t:f32[1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1,)] q
    u:f32[3] = concatenate[dimension=0] r s t
  in (u,) }
```

On the other hand, the `vmap` version lowers to just a single generalized dot product:

```py
print(jax.make_jaxpr(f_vmap)(x, y))
```

```
{ lambda ; a:f32[3,5] b:f32[3,5]. let
    c:f32[3] = dot_general[dimension_numbers=(([1], [1]), ([0], [0]))] a b
  in (c,) }
```

Notice that there is nothing concerning parallelization here; rather we've automatically created an efficient batched version of our operation. The same is true of `vmap` applied to more complicated functions: it does not involve parallelization, rather it outputs an efficient batched version of your operation in an automated manner.

Comment: First of all thank you for that explanation, that already cleared some things up for me. But i am still wondering, where the difference in memory usage is originating from between lax.map and vmap. I assumed some sort of parallization was happening because i observed an increase in GPU utilization and memory consumption compared to lax.map

Comment: `lax.map` is like the `for` loop operation: it executes one batch at a time. `lax.vmap` will construct batched operations that execute all at once. This generally requires more memory, but also allows the compiler to make more use of available compute on your GPU. Does that answer your question?